# Boto3: Assume role and use it to get events from CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

Developing a Glue Job, I'm trying to assume a role to get events from CloudWatch. I'm trying this way:

```
import boto3

cw_client = boto3.client('logs').assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::0000000000000000:role/custom-role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)

def get_cloudwatch_logs(log_group_name, log_stream_name):
    kwargs = {
        'logGroupName': log_group_name,
        'logStreamName': log_stream_name,
        'startTime': int((datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=24)).timestamp()),
        'endTime': int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
        'startFromHead': True,
    }
    response = cw_client.get_log_events(**kwargs)
    events = response['events']
    while response.get('nextForwardToken'):
        kwargs.update({'nextToken': response['nextForwardToken']})
        response = cw_client.get_log_events(**kwargs)
        events.extend(response['events'])
    return events

def transform_logs_to_dataframe(events):
    log_data = []
    for event in events:
        log_data.append(event['message'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(log_data, columns=['message'])
    return df
```

But it returns the error message:

> "AttributeError: 'CloudWatchLogs' object has no attribute 'assume_role'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sts` is the service used for assuming a role. once you have assumed the role, use the returned credentials to create a new `boto3.Session`:

```py
import boto3

creds = boto3.client('sts').assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::0000000000000000:role/custom-role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)['Credentials']
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken']
)
cw_client = session.client('logs')
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts/client/assume_role.html

> Returns a set of temporary security credentials that you can use to access Amazon Web Services resources. These temporary credentials consist of an access key ID, a secret access key, and a security token. Typically, you use AssumeRole within your account or for cross-account access.

Comment: once i have the sts_client created, how can i use it to get the logs from cloudwatch?

Comment: i tried and it worked!